# Compare a fine and a coarse time series at only the coarse scale

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I have two `data.frame`s in `R`, each indexed by date. One is coarser than the other and I would like to compare the data only along the coarser timescale.

To be more concrete let's say one `data.frame` has time points `DF1[a,b,c,...,x,y,z]` and the other only has `DF2[f,p,t]`, where `p=="July 19, 1917"`. I wish to compare `DF1[f,p,t]` to `DF2[f,p,t]`.

This isn't syntactic but I want to do  `for each $i { DF_combined <- df1[$i] . df2[$i] if exists(df1[$i]); }`. In other words, make a new `data.frame` that only contains every shared observation day.

I hope the question is clear. I've been looking at other SO answers for a couple of hours and haven't found one that covers what I'm trying to do yet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution to my problem, from start to finish.

**Problem:** Given records from my broker (not evenly spaced in time), put the time series of my net worth next to a time series of the S&P, for comparison in `R`.

**Answer**:

```
#get S&P data
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("^GSPC", from="2004-01-01", src="yahoo")
head(GSPC)

              GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted
2004-01-02   1111.92   1118.85  1105.08    1108.48  1153200000       1108.48
2004-01-05   1108.48   1122.22  1108.48    1122.22  1578200000       1122.22
2004-01-06   1122.22   1124.46  1118.44    1123.67  1494500000       1123.67
```

Notice that there is no header over the dates. That's because time-series data types embed the time-value as an ordering index. (`class(GSPC)` = `[1]  "xts" "zoo"` where `zoo` is a data type totally ordered by an index, and `xts` is a time series data-type that tolerates more than the restrictive native `ts` data type tolerates.)

```
#coerce the .csv from my broker into a time-series data type as well
MyNetWorth <- read.csv("/home/joey/Desktop/Historical_NAV.csv")
require(xts)
MyNetWorth <- as.xts( MyNetWorth,
                                   order.by= as.Date(MyNetWorth$TradeDate, format="%m/%d/%Y") )
```

In the date `format` there is a big difference between `%Y` ('87) and `%y` (1987), as well as between `%m` – months and `%M` – minutes. My broker wrote 10/23/2009.

So did I do it right?

```
> class(MyNetWorth)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

Yessss.

Finally, @Joshua Ulrich's advice does the kind of merge I want:

```
comparison <- merge(GSPC$GSPC.Adjusted, MyNetWorth$NetAssets, join="right")
```

The `right join` compares the dates only at the coarser scale (my data is always coarser than Yahoo's).

Last of all, to plot the results:

```
plot( as.zoo(comparison) , screens=c(1,1), col=c("red", "#333333")  )
```

Many thanks to all the people who wrote all this open source software — and especially to those who wrote vignettes!

Answer (score 3):

Merge your data.frames, then do whatever operations you want.

```
# assume the frequency of x > frequency of y (i.e. y is "coarse")
merge(x, y, by="row.names", all.y=TRUE)  # dates are in row.names
merge(x, y, by="date", all.y=TRUE)       # dates are in "date" column
```

Since you have a time-series, I would suggest you use a time-series class instead of a data.frame.  I recommend xts/zoo.  Here's how you would do this with xts:

```
merge(x, y, join="right")
```

Comment: Wow, I had a lot to learn. I guess totally ordered objects ⊃ irregular time series ⊃ time series, + headers, are a very specific data type after all. The open source community has done an amazing amount of work even in just the late 2000's, not even counting Chambers et al. Thanks for the right join hint as well, that would have been another fox hunt.